# Exclude Resource in kustomization.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a kustomize base that I'd like to re-use without editing it. Unfortunately, it creates a namespace I don't want to create. I'd like to simply remove that resource from consideration when compiling the manifests and add a resource for mine since I can't patch a namespace to change the name.

Can this be done? How?

Comment: Can you provide more information ? Tutorial you are using, your config files, environment you are working on.

Comment: Not really, this is an internal thing. I'll see about mocking up an example.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can omit the specific resource by using a delete directive of [Strategic Merge Patch](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-api-machinery/strategic-merge-patch.md#delete-directive) like this.

Folder structure

```
$ tree .
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── namespace.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── dev
    │   └── kustomization.yaml
    └── prod
        ├── delete-ns-b.yaml
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

File content

```
$ cat base/kustomization.yaml
resources:
  - namespace.yaml

$  cat base/namespace.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-a
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-b

$ cat overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml
bases:
  - ../../base

$ cat overlays/prod/delete-ns-b.yaml
$patch: delete
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-b

$ cat overlays/prod/kustomization.yaml
bases:
  - ../../base
patches:
  - path: delete-ns-b.yaml
```

Behavior of kustomize

```
$ kustomize build overlays/dev
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-a
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-b

$ kustomize build overlays/prod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns-a
```

In this case, we have two namespaces in the base folder. In dev, kustomize produces 2 namespaces because there is no patch. But, in prod, kustomize produces only one namespace because delete patch deletes namespace ns-b.

Comment: Toshinori-san, thank you for that solution, brilliant!

Comment: My pleasure!! :)

Comment: When I tried this with `kind: CronJob` I got a bunch of empty objects in the compiled manifest.

Comment: This is awesome. It even works inside of arrays, allowing you to delete or replace a sidecar for example, without resorting to json6902 patches. Really needs to be documented better though

Comment: Is there a way to define this path inline in a kustomization file? I've tried a few ways but I can only make it work if the patch is pointing to a file.

Comment: This approach worked for our situation - deploying OPA Gatekeeper via Argo CD without its Secret.  OPA Gatekeeper's manifest comes with an empty Secret that can get filled in later.  Being empty, it's not an issue to check into Git.  But we have Argo CD restricted so it doesn't mess with or monitor Secrets, and projects with Secrets show up in Argo CD with warnings.  Having the Kustomize project in Git filter out the empty Secret means the project looks clean in Argo CD.

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this problem and eventually took a different approach to solving it. It's worth thinking back through your requirements and asking yourself why you would want `kustomize` to omit a resource? In my case - and I would imagine this is the most common use-case - I wanted `kustomize` to omit a resource because I didn't want to apply it to the target kubernetes cluster but `kustomize` doesn't provide an easy way to do this. Would it not be better for the filtration to take place when applying the resource to the cluster rather than when generating them? The solution which I eventually applied was to filter the resources by label when applying to the cluster. You can add an exclusion label in an overlay to prevent the resource from being applied.

e.g.

```
$ kustomize build . | kubectl apply -l apply-resource!=no -f -
```

Comment: That's a neat solution for quick deployments, but will it work in the gitops use of Flux or ArgoCD? I also tend to prefer to make changes to the results as close to the original as possible to reduce confusion as it passes through the process. For some simple one-off situations where I don't need to automate and reproduce my results, this is elegant and quick.

Comment: I like this solution for quick tests too. But I dislike that the "-l" filter is missing in the VCS

Comment: Works very well, but a shorter version is 'kubectl apply -k . -l apply-resource!=no'

Comment: @stackoverflowed Not all kustomize features are supported natively by kubectl so those of us who have run into that generally just pipe and save the brain cells needed to figure out which circumstance we're in.

Answer (score 8):

I found that my understanding of not being able to change a namespace name was incorrect. Using the patch capability, you actually can change the name of a resource including namespaces.

This is what I ended up using:

```
patches:
- target:
    kind: Namespace
    name: application
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /metadata/name
      value: my-application
```