# Kustomize stuck deleting StatefulSets that uses PersistentVolumes

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am using Kustomize to manage my Kubernetes project with a StetefulSet that deploys a PostgreSQL cluster with three pods. I am working on Vagrant/VirtualBox so no dynamic provisioning of PV exists. For this reason, I have my own `pv.yaml` containing the manifest to deploy these 3 PVs.

Then I have a `kustomization.yaml` file like this:

```
namespace: ibm-cfdb

bases:
- ../../bases

resources:
- pv.yaml
```

the folder `../../bases` contains the file to deploy the StatefulSet. When I run:
`kubectl apply -k kustomize/` everything is correctly deployed. PVs are created before the StetefulSet that contains a `volumeClaimTemplates` that declare the Claim for these PVs.

The problem is that when I try to remove the deployment with the command:
`kubectl delete -k kustomize/` the removal of PV is executed (it seems I don't have control about the order). I suppose these PVs cannot be deleted because Claims use them. Then the StatefulSet removal stuck.

What is the best approach to manage PV static provisioning with Kustomize?

Comment: After a bit of investigation, I found that the Stateful removal doesn't remove PVCs and I understand it. The problem is that Kustomize should not call ```pv.yaml``` on delete. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Avoid executing `kubectl delete` for directories that contain PVCs if you don't want to delete them.

Comment: PVCs are not deleted. PVs are. To avoid issues I need to move PV to another folder but this adds another command to remember when I deploy the app. I hoped a feature like "ignore pv.yaml on delete" but I don't think it exists.

Comment: Try to use a dynamic volume provisioner, if available in your system - that way you don't have to create PVs yourself.

Comment: I know, my app deploys on Vagrant/VirtualBox where I use static provisioning and then the ```pv.yaml``` file. On IBM Cloud I use the dynamic provision and this issue doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered an interesting problem regarding StatefulSet and PVC removal. There is a [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55045) whether PVCs created by the StatefulSet should be deleted when deleting the corresponding StatefulSet. We recently received [information](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55045#issuecomment-824937931) that the feature to autodelete the PVCs created by StatefulSet will probably be available in the [1.23 release](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55045#issuecomment-884298382). According to the [feature documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-apps/1847-autoremove-statefulset-pvcs#changes-required), this will allow us to specifiy if the VolumeClaimTemplate PVCs will be deleted after deleting their StatefulSet.
I suspect that with this feature it'll be easy to delete your StatefulSet along with PVC and PV.

For now, you can consider moving the file with the PV to another directory and manage it separately.
However, I will propose another solution which is kind of a workaround but you may be interested.

Basically, we can use the `-o` flag with the `kustomize build` command. This creates one file per resource, which gives us more control over resources creation.

---

I will give you an example to illustrate how this can work.

Suppose I have a similar environment to you:

```
$ tree
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── statefulset.yaml
└── overlays
    └── dev
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── pv.yaml

$ cat overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml
bases:
  - ../../base

resources:
- pv.yaml
```

Now let's create a directory where our manifest files generated by `kustomize` will be stored:

```
$ mkdir generated_manifests
```

Then we can check if the command `kustomize build overlays/dev -o generated_manifests` works as expected. First we'll apply the generated manifests (it'll create the `web` StatefulSet and `pv0003` PersistentVolume):

```
$ kustomize build overlays/dev -o generated_manifests && kubectl apply -Rf generated_manifests/
statefulset.apps/web created
persistentvolume/pv0003 created
```

As you can see, the appropriate manifest files have been created in the `generated_manifests` directory:

```
$ ls generated_manifests/
apps_v1_statefulset_web.yaml  v1_persistentvolume_pv0003.yaml
```

Finally, we can try to delete only the `web` StatefulSet:

```
$ kustomize build overlays/dev -o generated_manifests && kubectl delete -f generated_manifests/apps_v1_statefulset_web.yaml
statefulset.apps "web" deleted
```

---

I would also like to mention that `kustomize` has a feature like "ignore pv.yaml" but it will also be used when creating resources, not just when removing. This is known as a delete patch and a good example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66074466/14801225).

Comment: Just read your solution. To be honest I simply separate the StatefulSet resources from PV resources and called them in separated files. When I remove them I first remove the StatefulSet, then the PVC, then the PV. I will analyze your proposal with more attention. For the moment I upvoted it.